# Style php code with css to get a html list

Tags: php, html, css

I have a question about styling php with css. In the code below is a navigation bar at the top of the page and it will include the page you selected. In the bottom code is how i prefer the layout, but i just can't get it to work for the php code. It is working atm but it is just text with a link color. i can't make a list like in the second code cause it is in a foreach loop.

How can i get the result i want?

Thanks in advance!!

```
<head>
<title>Website</title>
<style>
    body {margin:0;}

    ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #333;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }

    li {
        float: left;
    }

    li a {
        display: block;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    li a:hover:not(.active) {
        background-color: #111;
    }

    .active {
        background-color: #4CAF50;
    }
</style>


</head>
<body>

<?php

// This is your menu
$items = array("pagina1", "pagina2", "pagina3", "pagina4");
foreach ($items as $item)
{
if (isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == $item)
{
    echo '<a href="?page=' . $item . '" class="active"> ' . $item . '</a>';
    $activePage = $item . ".php";
}
else
{
    echo '<a href="?page=' . $item . '"> ' . $item . '</a>';
}
}

// Include your page
if (isset($activePage))
{
include $activePage;
}
else
{
include "pagina1.php";
}

?>

</body>
```

-

```
<head>
<style>
body {margin:0;}

ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #333;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
}

li 
float: left;
}

li a {
display: block;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #111;
}

.active {
background-color: #4CAF50;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
<li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>

<div style="padding:20px;margin-top:30px;background-     color:#1abc9c;height:1500px;">
<h1>Fixed Top Navigation Bar</h1>
<h2>Scroll this page to see the effect</h2>
<h2>The navigation bar will stay at the top of the page while scrolling</h2>

<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Are you trying to include a php-page with <head> tag into another page inside <body>-tag? I think this could cause the error   .... forget it, I did not understand your goal..

Answer (score 0):

You did not added ul and li tags.

```
    echo '<ul>';
foreach ($items as $item)
    {
echo '<li>';
    if (isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == $item)
    {
        echo '<a href="?page=' . $item . '" class="active"> ' . $item . '</a>';
        $activePage = $item . ".php";
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<a href="?page=' . $item . '"> ' . $item . '</a>';
    }
echo '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: Thand you so much. I added them already but without the echo. Now it is working!!

Answer (score 0):

You're not adding the `ul` structure.

```
<ul>

<?php

    // This is your menu
    $items = array("pagina1", "pagina2", "pagina3", "pagina4");
    foreach ($items as $item)
    {
        if (isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == $item)
        {
            echo '<li><a href="?page=' . $item . '" class="active"> ' . $item . '</a></li>';
            $activePage = $item . ".php";
        }
        else
        {
            echo '<li><a href="?page=' . $item . '"> ' . $item . '</a></li>';
        }
    }

?>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you begin your `foreach` loop, add `echo "<ul>";`.

Change the `echo` within the loop to begin with `<li>` and end with `</li>`.

Lastly, after your `foreach` loop, add `echo "</ul>";`.

Comment: It is working now, but the active button isn't another color anymore when you open the page. If you switch a page it will apear back, but not when you open the page.

Comment: @ProgrammerKid If you inspect the html when the page first opens, do you see the `active` class on one of the links?

Comment: no, in the beginning there is no current page so it will skip the if. it was more a question how i could do such a thing

Comment: If `pagina1` is the home/default page, you could assume that if `$_GET['page']` returns nothing that `pagina1` is active. You could add another `if` statement within the `else` statement for your menu items that looks like `else{ if ($item == 'pagina1') { echo '<a href="?page=' . $item . '" class="active"> ' . $item . '</a>'; } else { echo '<a href="?page=' . $item . '"> ' . $item . '</a>'; }}` You may need to tweak that a bit, but it should be close.